# LiveReload configuration via Grunt

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, grunt, livereload

#### Edit : about the possible duplicate !

I would like to mention that [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122515/magento-2-livereload) answer does not answer my question, if someone sees that it is the same thing, I invite him to answer me instead of saying that he is duplicated and we will see if it solves my problem.

I think that when **looking** for something, the first reflex is to search if there was already the same question as mine that **was asked before**, and I saw this post and it does not answer my problem! and even more there is not a reliable answer or accepted !

---

Does anyone ever work or still work with the `liveReload` via grunt ?

- I have some problem, i don't know why but the liveReload dont refresh th content changed automatically.
- I have grunt installed and it works fine i can `clean`, `exec`, etc but, when i enter: `grunt watch` he watch well the changes, example: if i change `mycustom.css`, he display :

> > > File "pub/static/frontend/Package/theme/fr_FR/css/mycustom.css" changed. Completed in 0.001s at Wed Mar 21 2018 16:08:58 GMT+0100
> > >       (CET) - Waiting...

But he doesn't refresh the page,(when i refresh it manually, i see well my changes) is there a configuration to do in `grunt` or in the `server` ?

- I also wanted to mention that the `liveReload browser extension`  is well installed but does not work, ie when I press on a logo, it shows me an error message:

> Could not connect to LiveReload server. Please make sure that
>   LiveReload 2.3 (or later) or another compatible server is running.

Comment: Please also look at my Q&A, I also had alot of trouble and was able to make it run finally, might be helpful: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/306011/magento-2-livereload-is-connected-but-changes-are-only-visible-after-manual-r/306028#306028

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's been two days since the post is open and no one has found the answer to my question, and working hard on this topic **I finally found the solution**. So I decided **to publish the complete solution**, the installation of `Grunt` and then `Livereload` and how to configure both together because I found that they are very useful tools for **Magento2** and even more for the **frontend developers**

###Let's start:

**What is LiveReload ?**

For those who don't know what is **LiveReload**, LiveReload monitors changes in the file system. As soon as you save a file, it is preprocessed as needed, and the browser is refreshed.

Even cooler, when you change a CSS file or an image, the browser is updated instantly without reloading the page.

I find this beautiful because for a developer Magento when it is in full development or integration he is obliged to refresh the page manually to see the result, then he goes back on his code he update, he saves, he clean the cache, then he returns to the browser , he refresh the browser and so on, while with the **liveReload** it's over all that, it is just enough to save the update and 'Hoop' magically the content that you have changed instantaneously appear without refreshing the browser and without cleaning the cache, deploying the static-content either but for the cache, you also need **Grunt** but I explain in detail how to put this.

**What is Grunt ?**

Grunt is a **JavaScript Task Runner**, a tool that allows you to create automated tasks in JavaScript,

it is very useful for `Magento 2` because by its configuration, it allows us to removes the theme related static files in the `pub/static` and `var` directories,  set up the `.less` files, and especially the `watch` that observes the changes of the files and which it is indispensable for the our `liveReload`

**Now the installation :**

###Grunt:

> **Important** : be sure that you are in `developer mode`, in `root` project location when you execute the command bellow.
>
> Rename the `package.json.sample` to `package.json`,
> `Gruntfile.js.sample` to `Gruntfile.js`

1. We have to install [npm node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) on your machine : `sudo apt-get install npm`
2. Install Grunt CLI :  `npm install -g grunt-cli`
3. Refresh nodejs : `npm install`
4. To make sure that the **npm** is well installed the `npm -v` should output something like: `5.7.1`, for **Grunt** `grunt --version` should output something like: `grunt-cli v1.2.0`
5. Grunt theme configuration: go to : `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js` then add your current theme name that you are used, assuming that your theme name is : `Prince/amir` in : `app/design/frontend/Prince/amir` so you add the following in `module.exports`like this:

   ```
    module.exports = {
    ...
    prince: { // for the clean command
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Prince/amir', //Vendor/theme
        locale: 'fr_FR', //locale
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l',
            'css/custom' // for custom.less for example 
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    ...
    },
   ```
6. You can use `grunt clean:prince` to removes the theme related static files in the `pub/static` and `var` directories.
7. Save
   . [More informations](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html)

###LiveReload:

1. `npm install -g livereload`
2. To make sure that the liveReload is well installed, `livereload -v` should output the version something like : `0.7.0`
3. Install the `LiveReload browser extension`, available for **Chrome** and **Firfox**.
4. Add the script line bellow inside `<head>` tag in  `default.xml` or `default_head_blocks.xml` of your current theme example : `app/design/frontend/Prince/amir/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="http://200.120.00.01:35729/livereload.js" src_type="url"></script>
    </head>
   ```

Here as you see there is an **IP**(200.120.00.01) address plus the **port**(35729) plus **livereload.js** file

**So what to do:** replace this `IP` with your IP project, the `port` remains the same dont change it `35729` and the `livereload.js` you copy it in your root project, you can get it from the livereload installation(remember we installed it before) the path is: `/usr/lib/node_modules/livereload/ext/livereload.js`, or from this [github](https://github.com/livereload/livereload-js/tree/master/dist).

###it's time to practice:

Run `grunt clean`, `grunt less`, `grunt execute` (sometimes magento doesn't work well with livereload if it has not been executed before) and then

1. We launch the **Grunt watch** to monitor our files changes.
2. Check if the **LiveReload browser extension icon** is well activated, in Firefox the icon comes green, in Chrome the small dot inside the circle becomes full black

**important :** if everything is good, if you enter in your browser your `IP:35729` example : `200.120.00.01:35729`, you'll see some welcome message like:

> tinylr   "Welcome"

> version   "0.2.1"

3. Open your custom.css for example then change something then save, here you'll see in `grunt watch` some new line appears tells that this file has been changed something like:

> File "pub/static/frontend/Prince/amir/fr_FR/css/custom.css" changed.

and look now your browser, Hoop the item that you just changed appeared and updated instantly without reloading the page, also without cleaning the cache or deploying the static-content, everything is done automatically.

here I am finished, I hope you will enjoy this, it is really useful tool.

Good luck.

Comment: Glad you finally got it working, I'm not going to use this though as I don't trust myself not to accidentally commit the XML to the codebase, I wouldn't like to see that end up on production.

Comment: @BenCrook - look at the RemoteLiveReload browser extension for Chrome, the "official" LiveReload only connects to localhost:335729. Also see my answer on https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/225390/289 for more debugging tips

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, fortunately I don't use Grunt anymore so this isn't an issue for me.

Comment: My project is design by CoffeeScript and no `default.xml` file found, how to change ip address in my project. (in livereload step 4)

Comment: My location of livereload on Ubuntu: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/livereload/bin/livereload.js

Comment: Just so you know according to the livereload.js github repo they suggest using 
        `<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js" src_type="url"></script>`.

Comment: I also had plenty of problems and even your answer was not solving my issues. I finally figured it all out: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/306011/magento-2-livereload-is-connected-but-changes-are-only-visible-after-manual-r/306028#306028

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in enx.php, it will be ignored in git

```
    'system' => [
        'default' => [
            'design' => [
                'footer' => [
                    'absolute_footer' => '<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```