# "Best practice" editing CSS while in development to avoid cache rebuild time

Tags: magento2, css, cache, less

I'm building my first Magento site after spending the last few years developing sites with other eCommerce engines - wow, Magento does *everything* differently huh?!

Not really best practice but how do you work with CSS/Less/Sass while you're developing a site? I'm currently extending the CSS using _extend.less and have separate .less files for each section, such as body, typefaces and the product page.

But I'm finding refreshing the cache after each edit is getting in the way of my workflow.

How do you speed up your development time? Do you have a separate CSS file called from head that you merge at go-live time? Or do you disable the cache? Or do you do some other trick?

Interested to know - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To speed up theme development, you can utilize Grunt and LiveReload to automatically update changes in the browser without needing to refresh the page or redeploy static content.

Here is an open source module with installation instructions at https://github.com/toandp/magento2-livereload

Here are some posts discussing Grunt and LiveReload that you may find helpful:

- [LiveReload configuration via Grunt](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219265/livereload-configuration-via-grunt)
- [Grunt, .less, and Live Reload - Can't get them working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225034/grunt-less-and-live-reload-cant-get-them-working)
- [Magento 2 - LiveReload is connected, but changes are only visible after manual reload](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/306011/magento-2-livereload-is-connected-but-changes-are-only-visible-after-manual-r)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I'd looked at Grunt before but couldn't get to install correctly. Have given it another bash this morning and success. Thanks :)

Comment: Cool! You're welcome!