# Debug css in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, less

I read the page: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

And I am trying to see the code from the less file rather than the css so that I can debug the styling in Magento 2.

Currently, my Chrome browser has css source map enabled and also I use the default luma style. Also, I have installed grunt and compile the style: grunt exec:luma

Yet, when I inspect the style, the debugger shows the css.

Comment: you are using grunt and still you don't see respective .less file , right ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure double check **Gruntfile.js** file locate in root https://www.screencast.com/t/FMwyxqhno0e

If not available in root rename

> Gruntfile.js.sample

to

> Gruntfile.js

Than run CLI command

```
grunt --force clean:luma && php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy css/styles-m css/styles-l --type=less --locale=en_US --area=frontend --theme=Magento/luma &&

grunt exec:luma && php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy css/styles-m css/styles-l --type=less --locale=en_US --area=frontend --theme=Magento/luma &&

grunt less:luma && php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy css/styles-m css/styles-l --type=less --locale=en_US --area=frontend &&

php bin/magento cache:clean &&

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two mode in LESS compiltation:

1. Client-side compilation : for not production mode, using the native `less.js` library.
2. Server compilation : just for the production mode.

You can set that in admin : `Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Store View > Front-end development workflow`.

To see the changes, you have to remove the `pub/static` **content**. and by doing this so many times, and every time you make a change, it becomes annoying and not necessarily practical. so **grunt** is a good thing for that.instead of clearing all this manually, **grunt** will do it for you, you just have to configure it properly. [More informations](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html).

I wrote a post with the complete configuration and with examples.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/219573/48355

hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for your answer, however, the question I had was how can we show the less files in the browser for debug purpose. The answer below does the trick by compiling the less files.