# Magento 2 - LiveReload is connected, but changes are only visible after manual reload

Tags: magento2, less, grunt, magento2.3.4, livereload

I try to use `grunt watch` in combination with **livereload**. But there is almost no documentation on the topic.

---

I installed livereload like this:

```
npm install -g livereload
```

Then I added the following line to "**THEME\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml**":

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="http://www.example.com:35729/livereload.js" src_type="url"></script>
    ...
</head>
```

> **NOTE**: Of course replace www.example.com with your domain

Then I flushed the cache.

---

Now I executed `grunt watch`.

If I reload the site and hover over the icon I get:

[image]

**"LiveReload is connected, click to disable"**

If I change a .less file, then the files are successfully recompiled by grunt watch, but the changes are not shown in the browser, only after I reload manually.

---

If I call "http://**enter_ip_of_your_server_here**:35729/livereload.js" in the browser directly, then I get "**website not reachable**".

Comment: Have you started grunt watch and does your mode is developer mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message "LiveReload is connected" is wrong and misleading.

I tried it again on a fresh magento 2.3.4 on my own linux server.

I did all the steps described in my question.

If I call "http://**www.example.com**:35729/livereload.js" in the browser directly, then I get:

```
{"tinylr":"Welcome","version":"0.2.1"}
```

So this means it works! There the changes are visible without reloading and the plugin works as expected!

> **NOTE**: Make sure to use http and not https, otherwise it wont work!

But back to my other server where it does not work yet...

I figured out that the port **35729** is getting blocked, so I asked my hoster to unblock it. The hoster opened the ports, now I finally got:

```
{"tinylr":"Welcome","version":"0.2.1"}
```

when calling `http://enter_ip_of_your_server_here:35729/livereload.js` in the browser directly!

But the plugin does still fail and does not reload the content on change...

I figured out that if I start `livereload` directly in the terminal, that I get alot of error messages containing:

**Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached**

So the problem must be that the limit of file watchers is reached.

You can check the max value with `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`.

For me it returns `8192` but on the other working server it is set to `65536`.

My hoster increased the value, the errors disapeared, but the LiveReload extension still failed.

So I opened the browsers developer tools and inspected the console and network traffic. I figured out that "liveload.js" was unable to load:

[image]

I figured out that I get this message in the browser console, because I serve the script with http instead of https, because otherwise it wont work and now there is [mixed content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content):

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://example.com/customer/account/index/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://example.com:35729/livereload.js'. This request has
>   been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I followed this [guide on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24434461/4684797) to bypass this and now it finally works!