# Magento 2.4 alternatives to Livereload Chrome extension for live styling via Grunt?

Tags: magento2.4, grunt, livereload

Magento officially recommends Livereload for "watching" changes made via Grunt and updating the browser in real-time without reloading the page for each change here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html#add_theme

The problem is that Livereload has not been maintained and updated since 2015 and is basically unusable for me on OS X 10.15. For example the Chrome extension often falls into an infinite reloading loop which causes my browser to DOS my own server by sending an update request for the current page every second.

Can anybody recommend another app or workflow for live-updating the browser during Magento 2 development using Grunt as provided by Magento?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LiveReload configuration via Grunt](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219265/livereload-configuration-via-grunt)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not, as there are simply too many issues with Livereload to fix and so I am looking for an alternative. It seems that Livereload development has completely ceased.

Comment: @LouisB. did you ever find an alternative?

Comment: @grok_in_full: Yes, I am now just using command line SASS to compile my files, and Live Reload only to watch the changed CSS files, as it can no longer compile SCSS files.